# How can I set a logo in the navigation bar for all view controllers from a central place

Tags: ios, swift

How can I set a logo in the navigation bar for all view controllers from a central place?
I mean, I wouldn't like to set the logo in the code of every view controller (viewDidLoad()) method.
Is there a good place to put that, like Appdelegate or an event that is fired after every screen change? 
I put the code below in Appdelegate but just worked for the initial screen. Thanks.

```
    let img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Tourney"))
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let logo =  UIBarButtonItem(customView: img)

    let root = window?.rootViewController!
    root?.childViewControllers[0].childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logo
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make a BaseViewController in which you set that logo in navigation item and then make other controllers extend BaseViewController. Now you will be able to see that logo in all controllers.

```
public class BaseViewController : UIViewController {

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       setNavigationImage(..........)
    }

}

public class FirstViewController : BaseViewController {
    ........
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about a native event which could be used to access the current displayed view controller and set the logo, then removing the need to call the base event in each view controller, even though it is just one line to call the method. But okay, it is a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

extension UIViewController  and  adding a method `setupNavigationBar` for setup navigation center image .

```
extension UIViewController { 
    func setupNavigationBar(image: UIImage) {
        //set your image navigation bar center
        //set titile
        //self.navigationItem.title =  title 
        //set image in the center 
         self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
    }
}
```

now `setupNavigationBar` all viewcontroller and try to call this way

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.setupNavigationBar(image: UIImage(named: "Tourney"))
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about a native event which could be used to access the current displayed view controller and set the logo, then removing the need to call the base event in each view controller, even though it is just one line to call the method. But okay, it is a nice approach.

Comment: it is exactly same what you want . did you try with my answer . however when your need to set navigation bar center image then call this method with pass image name `self.setupNavigationBar(image: UIImage(named: "Tourney"))` and another event just remove image just call this method with empty image name or nil   `self.setupNavigationBar(image: UIImage(named: ""))` .

Comment: @AlvaroCryptogram would you accept my answer please if it is help you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a BaseViewController and add it into ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.yellow

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let image = UIImage(named: "Apple_Swift_Logo")
    imageView.image = image

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

Which ever controller you want to use it just extend the controller to BaseViewController like following

```
class ChildViewController: BaseViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}

Comment: I was thinking about a native event which could be used to access the current displayed view controller and set the logo, then removing the need to call the base event in each view controller, even though it is just one line to call the method. But okay, it is a nice approach.